I am trying to start Unity on AWS headless Linux Ubuntu 20.04. I have Unityhub installed, but the unity hub --headless install fails
Here is the full command I using unityhub --headless install --version 2022.3.1f1 -m android --cm. I get one of two errors, and the first one is:
Here is the error I get.
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.p3KEN6: failed to map segment from shared object
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2049)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1011:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/unityhub/resources/app.asar/node_modules/diskusage/index.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:14)
Trace/breakpoint trap

The new error I get now after installing more packages is this:
Illegal instruction

The AWS node is a AMD CPU and not Intel.
